# CMake and HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN when cross-compiling PCL

Tags: c++, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile pcl-1.8.1 for ARM in Docker with Jetson toolchain (GCC 4.8.5). During CMake configure I get:

```
...

-- Performing Test HAVE_MM_MALLOC
-- Performing Test HAVE_MM_MALLOC - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN_EXITCODE (advanced)
For details see /pcl-1.8.1/build/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Performing Test HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN - Failed
-- -- GCC > 4.3 found, enabling -Wabi
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success

...
```

Does someone by any change know what this `HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN_EXITCODE` is and what the value should be in this case? Why is this failing in the first place?

I have already successfully built `Boost` with this same setup so the compiler is working.

Edit: Ok, now I understood it's the exit code for `HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [try_run](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/try_run.html) command CMake compiles and **run** some **code**.

If *cross-compile*, the code cannot be run (it can be run on the *target* machine, not on the *host* machine where configuration is performed), so CMake asks for help.

Variable's name *HAVE_POSIX_MEMALIGN_EXITCODE* suggests, that test for POSIX_MEMALIGN feature is needed to be run, and the variable contains result of that test.

1. If you know the feature is supported on the target machine, you may set the *cache variable* to `0` (which means "success"). Or you may set the variable to any non-zero value, if the feature is not supported on the target machine.
2. Alternatively, you may copy test's executable to the target machine, run it there, and check result. After that, set the cache variable in accordance to that result.
3. Also, modern CMake supports setting of the *emulator*, so CMake can run cross-compiled executable without manual intervention from the user. See description of [CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR.html) variable.